# WPF TextBox obtain and set caret position from mouse pointer

Tags: wpf, textbox, mouse, coordinates, caret

I am trying to set TextBox caret position according to the mouse coordinates when hovering over the TextBox. 
I can obtain the mouse coordinates relative to the TextBox by using Mouse.GetPosition(this.MyTextBox) but I need help translating those coordinates into the caret position.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you should try simulating mouse click event in you TextBox and pass the mouse position as event arguments

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4619597/620360) in related question.

Answer (score 4):

```
MyTextBox.CaptureMouse();
MyTextBox.CaretIndex = MyTextBox.GetCharacterIndexFromPoint(Mouse.GetPosition(MyTextBox), true);
```

Answer (score -1):

MyTextBox.GetCharacterIndexFromPoint(..) this returns the zero based index of the character that is closest to the specified point.
please see the link below:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.getcharacterindexfrompoint.aspx