# WPF: How do I get X Y position of last character within a TextBox?

Tags: wpf

I want to have the  x, y position of the last character in a TextBox. I found **GetCharacterIndexFromPoint** method which exactly is a reverse approach. => [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619484/how-do-i-convert-x-y-position-within-a-textbox-to-a-text-index)

However, I couldn't find the appropriate approach for getting actual position of last character within a TextBox.

Does anyone know how I can get such information?

Comment: Please explain what are you trying to do

Comment: Have you tried to look at the GetCharacterIndexFromPoint  sources?

Comment: @Gliad I'm trying to implement a blinking caret without focusing on the TextBox. Since I couldn't find a method for showing caret without focusing, I'm now trying to simulate caret after the last character using animation.

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty old now, but I want to give it a try.

**My solution for getting the actual position of last character within a TextBox:**

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Label Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Enter First Text: " FontSize="20"/>
    <TextBox Name="TextBox" Margin="10" Width="200" LostFocus="TextBox_OnLostFocus"/>
    <Button Content="GetPositionFromLastCharacter" Width="200" Click="GetLastCharacterFromTextBox"/>
    <Label Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Enter second Text: " FontSize="20"/>
    <TextBox Margin="10" Width="200"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Method "GetLastCharacterFromTextBox" in MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
private void GetLastCharacterFromTextBox(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int lastCharacterPosition = TextBox.Text.LastIndexOf(TextBox.SelectedText, StringComparison.CurrentCulture);
    MessageBox.Show($"Last character from the Text is at position: {lastCharacterPosition}");
}
```

Output:
[WPF Application running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ0Zp.png)

As you can see, I used the "LastIndexOf" Method with the selected text in the TextBox.

**Suggestion for showing caret without focusing:**

Use the "LostFocus" property on a TextBox and implement the following code:

```
private void TextBox_OnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

The result is the following:
[Showing caret without focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWMFb.png)

Even though I have no focus on the first TextBox anymore, the caret is still visible.