# Select All Content of TextBox on GotFocus Event

Tags: .net, wpf, textbox, wpf-controls, focus

I am working on WPF application, in which I have some text boxes which is displaying dollar amount. I just want to select all content inside my text box whenever focus will come on text box.

To achieve the same I am using SelectAll() method of the text box on 'GotFocus' event, but it doesn't work as desire.

Kindly let me know how can I get functional. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on startup, register a global event handler for textbox
e.g

```
 EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.TextBoxBase), UIElement.GotFocusEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(TextBoxBaseGotFocus));
```

with the TextBoxBaseGotFocus method being something like this:

```
    private static void TextBoxBaseGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     // Get the TextBoxBase
     var elem = sender as System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.TextBoxBase;
     if (elem != null)
     {
         elem.SelectAll();
     }
}
```

Comment: This works great for keyboard focus, but when the mouse is used to switch focus it can deselect immediately - which feels a bit odd. It's detailed here but solutions are much more lengthy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660554/how-to-automatically-select-all-text-on-focus-in-wpf-textbox

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried handling FocusableChanged event 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.focusablechanged.aspx

You can check IsFocused inside FocusableChanged event handler. if IsFocused is true, you can call SelectAll
Following is the pseudo code

```
textBox.FocusableChanged += (s,e) =>
{
   if(textBox.IsFocused)
     testBox.SelectAll();
}
```

EDIT1
 As Above is not working,  You can try FocusManger.GetFocusedElement.
[determining-the-focused-element](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/luc/archive/2010/08/05/silverlight-wpf-debugging-determining-the-focused-element.aspx)

```
public DebugFocusedElementProxy()
{
    var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
    timer.Tick += (o, ea) =>
    {
        var fe = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement();
        if (fe != null)
        {
            var element = fe as FrameworkElement;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.Name) &&
                 String.Equals(element.Name, textBox))
            {
                textBox.SelectAll();
            }
        }
    };
    timer.Start();
}
```

//Beware that textBox.SelectAll might require to be called on [Dispatcher Thread](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/working-with-the-wpf-dispatcher)

Comment: I tried above approach but in code behind file attached event doesn't fire.

Comment: If that is not working, ugly way is to use FocusManager.GetFocusedElement, and timer event (as there is no event in FocusManageR)

Comment: Yes, this is very expensive way to use FocusManager.GetFocusedElement as it require thread.

Comment: Can I bind events (GotKeyBoardFocus and MouseCapture) using style for the text box.

Comment: Binding does not happen on events. if you are using .net 4.0, (or silverlight 3.0 onwards), you can use [TriggerAction](http://joyfulwpf.blogspot.in/2009/05/writing-custom-triggeraction-using.html) or [Behavior](http://www.wpftutorial.net/Behaviors.html). TriggerActions/Behaviors allow to attach event handlers to Command like syntax, where data binding can be used. But I am not sure whether events will be fired, because as you have mentioned they are not working as desired.

Comment: Thanks Tilak, It worked for me. I have used EventSetter within style to attach handler for GotKeyBoardFocus and MouseCapture events. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create an attached behavior for this and use it for desired textbox. This approch is explained in detail here -

http://eladm.wordpress.com/2009/04/02/attached-behavior/

code for such behavior is also available [here](http://thumbler.googlecode.com/svn-history/r4/trunk/Thumbler/View/TextBoxBehavior.cs) & [here](https://trac.cc.jyu.fi/projects/gko/browser/WPF/DrawAnywhere/trunk/DrawAnywhere/Utils/SelectAllOnFocus.cs?rev=268)

If you want all the textboxes in your application to have this by default then look here -

[How to Select All Text in a WPF TextBox on Focus](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/post/How-to-Select-All-Text-in-a-WPF-Content-on-Focus.aspx)