# Textbox SelectAll not working correctly

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the requirement that whenever a TextBox gets Focus (via Touch, Mouse, Keyboard) that all Text should be selected.

I tried with the `GotFocus` event and with the `OnMouseDown`/`OnMouseUp` (for mouse) events:

```
if (this.SelectionLength == 0)
{
    this.Focus();
    this.SelectAll();
}
```

but this is not working in all cases.

Sometimes I need to click twice into a TextBox, sometimes not.

Is the a definitive answer here?

Comment: Do you really want mouse clicks to focus all the contents of the textbox?  This effectively makes it so you cannot change a single letter of a word, only retype the whole thing.

Comment: pretty much definitive http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660554/how-to-automatically-select-all-text-on-focus-in-wpf-textbox

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia yes, sadly.

Comment: Post the other bits of code please.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate question. I can confirm that the linked question is identical (but bad to find via Google)

Comment: While you write a title for your Question SO would have suggested this question to you :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, maybe you should have quickly checked your assumption, before commenting... I just did (out of curiosity) and that other post was *not* suggested, although strangely, it *was* in the close dialog.

Comment: @Sheridan Me too tried out of curiosity. Try this(Textbox SelectAll wpf) SO suggests that question

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, that is strange indeed... maybe *I* should have checked *that* before *I* commented. :)

Answer (score 0):

We have two types of focus availables in WPF logical and Keyboard. for you can use eighter of them

For KeyBoard.

```
Keyboard.Focus(myControl);
```

For Logical

```
 FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, myControl);
```