# WPF Propagating GotFocus over the visualtree

Tags: c#, wpf

I Have this Style template

```
    <Style x:Key="placeHolder" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Text,
                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                                            Mode=TwoWay,
                                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                             x:Name="textSource" 
                             Background="Transparent" 
                             Focusable="True"
                             Panel.ZIndex="2">                            
                    </TextBox>
                    <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Panel.ZIndex="1">
                        <TextBox.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Text, Source={x:Reference textSource}}" Value="">
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>                                         
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </TextBox.Style>
                    </TextBox>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And In a Custom Control have a fiel that uses this template:

```
<TextBox x:Name="DatoABuscar" 
            Height="Auto" 
            MinHeight="25" 
            Text="{Binding Filtro,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
            Margin="1,1,1,0" 
            PreviewKeyDown="DatoABuscar_PreviewKeyDown" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Style="{StaticResource placeHolder}"
            Tag="{x:Static resources:Labels.CONTROLES_SearchPlaceHoderText}"
            GotFocus="DatoABuscar_GotFocus"/>
```

As you cold see I have a **GotFocus** handler with this code:

```
private void DatoABuscar_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((TextBox)sender).SelectAll();        
}
```

This handle Works perfect and I pretend to select all the content of the textbox when GotFocus Happens, but If I understand the real textbox showed after GotFocus happen is **textSource** inner into the style template.

Now My Questions are?

1. How can I do to propagate the got focus received by **DatoAbuscar** to **textSource**? 
   or
2. How can i do to Access the visualtree under the **DatoABuscar** to get **textSource**?
   or
3. How can i do to Select all text in **textSource** when **DatoAbuscar** recieves the GotFocus**?

Another aproach ?

**EDIT:** I'm totally wrong the problem isn't the TexBox where I'm selecting the text. My problema was the method to select the text. Finally I Implement [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2674291/1201782)

Comment: you need to get the grid control, loop its children of type textbox, then each of it select the text..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you only need to use [FindName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to find the "textSource".

```
private void DatoABuscar_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var txt = sender as TextBox;
    var innerTxt = txt.Template.FindName("textSource", txt) as TextBox;
    Keyboard.Focus(innerTxt);
    innerTxt.SelectAll();
}
```

Comment: It sounds better. let me try it

Comment: It seems to work. SelectionStrart and SelectionLenght boot have values but the UI doesn´t show the text selected

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez, check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660554/how-to-automatically-select-all-text-on-focus-in-wpf-textbox) it might be a problem with choosing the right event, but as long as you have found the `textSource`, you only need to fix the `text selection part`

Comment: Tks, My aproach was out of mind. your post recomendation help to solve my real problem.