# Selecting all contents of TextBox on clicking it

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I have one TextBox. On clicking it, all the contents of the TextBox should be selected. What is the solution for this?
The code I have tried is:

```
<TextBox Name="questionTitle_textBox" Text="Question title" PreviewMouseDown="questionTitle_textBox_PreviewMouseDown"/>
```

The function `questionTitle_textBox_PreviewMouseDown` is defined as

```
private void questionTitle_textBox_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
        questionTitle_textBox.SelectAll();
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660554/how-to-automatically-select-all-text-on-focus-in-wpf-textbox

Comment: @PaulF that answer is very complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works

```
<TextBox Name="questionTitle_textBox" Text="Question title" GotFocus="questionTitle_textBox_GotFocus" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="questionTitle_textBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
```

and in code behind

```
private void questionTitle_textBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = (sender as TextBox);
    if (tb != null)
    {
        if (!tb.IsFocused)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            tb.Focus();
        }
    }
}

private void questionTitle_textBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = (sender as TextBox);
    if (tb != null)
    {
        tb.SelectAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add a trigger to your TextBox

```
<TextBox Name="questionTitle_textBox" Text="Question title" >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
            <local:SelectAllAction />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

Add `SelectAllAction.cs` to your project:

```
namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public class SelectAllAction : TriggerAction<TextBox>
    {
        protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
        {
            if(this.AssociatedObject != null)
            {
                this.AssociatedObject.SelectAll();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You also need to add two namepsaces to your XAML to use the trigger. The name of my project was WpfApplication1, so you will probably need to change that:

```
xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace" 
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

Comment: Its not working. Same results what I got in the original post.

Comment: Its still not working. Same results what I got in the original post. Is it working for you?

Comment: Moreover, in Designer/XAML view, it is giving `Invalid Markup`. Although it builds, I have to comment `<local:SelectAllAction/>` to see the Designer/XAML View.

Comment: I suspect that you have a mismatch between the namespace you specify in XAML and the one you have specified for the `SelectAllAction` class. Make sure to replace "YourNameSpace" with whatever your namespace is both in XAML and the code behind. Please let me know if it works.