# How to reroute click event to a double click?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to reroute a Click event to act like a Double Click instead.
For example if I double click a TextBox it will select all the text so you can edit, I want a single click to do the same.

Is it possible to reroute events like this and if so how does one do so?
Thanks!

Comment: Extract method from your Double Click event handler method, implement Click event and invoke that extracted method.

Comment: @Unhek This may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660554/how-to-automatically-select-all-text-on-focus-in-wpf-textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the single click event handler, do the following:

```
var newMouseEvent = new MouseButtonEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 0, MouseButton.Left) 
{ 
    RoutedEvent = Control.MouseDoubleClickEvent
};
myTextBox.RaiseEvent(newMouseEvent);
```

Comment: did not fix my issues, but answers what I asked for, tnx!