# How to select all text in TextBox WPF when focused?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have tried the below code to select all text in textbox when focus. But this is not working.

**XAML**:

```
        <TextBox Text="test1" Width="100" Height="200"  
           GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus"></TextBox>
```

**c#:**

```
private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            (sender as TextBox).SelectAll();    
            //(sender as TextBox).Select(0, (sender as TextBox).Text.Length);
            (sender as TextBox).Focus();  
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

I have tried with asynchronous also. Surf lots , but nothing works.
Please suggest?

Comment: Duplicate `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660554/how-to-automatically-select-all-text-on-focus-in-wpf-textbox`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automatically select all text on focus in WPF TextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660554/how-to-automatically-select-all-text-on-focus-in-wpf-textbox)

Answer (score 19):

You could use the dispatcher:

```
private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    textBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => textBox.SelectAll()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. it's working. can you explain why we invoke the method inside the Dispatcher. Is there any specific reason for that?

Comment: It's basically a timing issue. `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` schedules the delegate that call `SelectAll()` to be executed when the UI thread is idle.

Answer (score 17):

in App.xaml file

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <EventSetter Event="GotKeyboardFocus" Handler="TextBox_GotKeyboardFocus"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

in App.xaml.cs file

```
private void TextBox_GotKeyboardFocus(Object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
    tb.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => tb.SelectAll()));
}
```

With this code you reach all TextBox in your Application